# fire base custom search is stuck

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am doing firebase programming with iOS.
I could do normal searching with code like below

```
ref.child("Users").queryOrderedByChild("name").queryStartingAtValue(text).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        for u in snapshot.children{
            print(user.name)
        }
    })
```

but i am confused, as i want to find people near me. every record has lat long values, where in the server i would put code to evaluate distance between my current location and friends location and filter them ? I dont want to loop through all items in above for block (Client side)

Also, can i write server code to make services hosted in firebase ? what is the recommended way to get data from big server like redshift ?

Is firebase really drag-drop development ? i did not find anything of that sort in firebase documentation ! firbase-ui is open source, but it gives obj c code and no drag and drop ! request answer please

Comment: "Also, can i write server code to make services hosted in firebase" of course you can, use the amazing Firebase Functions. You will see it right there on the Console, with full documentation.

Comment: thanks, but what language ? can you please help me with some example, i am lost